# TreeView added to object not showing up in UI

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am trying to create a dialog where the user selects a node in a TreeView so that he can save  some data to that node.

The tree itself is created in a separate control (that is used for browsing/opening content of nodes) and my idea is that i should use that tree in my save control.

My constructor looks like this:

```
public FrmSaveToRepository(TreeView tree)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.treeView = tree;
}
```

but when the form holding the control pops up the treeView is empty. Did i miss a step?

I open my form with this code:

```
var frm = new FrmSaveToRepository(tree);
frm.Show();
```

Comment: How you are calling `FrmSaveToRepository`?

Comment: Where do you add the treeview? I mean do you add it somewhere to the new form with this.Controls.Add(this.treeView)?

Comment: @Rahul The FrmSaveToRepository is a constructor to my form.

Comment: @Vajura the treeview is within the form created with the mentioned constructor. I just drag/drop-ed it to the screen in VS2012 :)

Comment: What I mean to check, how you are opening the form? Is `TreeView tree` null/empty?

Comment: @DenisKralj oh sorry i forget sometimes that you can use that :). Anyways try this this.treeView.Nodes = tree.Nodes. Also btw are you from slovenia?

Comment: @Vajura close neighbor ^^. anyway when i try this.treeView.Nodes = tree.Nodes i get: Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.Nodes' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Oh try it like this then this.treeView.Nodes.Add(this.tree.Nodes[0]); Sorry i forgot the right syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so the correct way to add the old nodes to the new tree is:

```
public FrmSaveToRepository(TreeView tree)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (TreeNode node in tree.Nodes)
    {
        this.treeView1.Nodes.Add(node.Clone() as TreeNode);
    }
}
```

but that still means that all the events and handlers have to be implemented separately in the new tree.